# Checkbox list always select the last record

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Hi I got the problem when bind the selected value to the checkboxlist. I already get the correct data count but I dont know it always bind to the last checkbox item. Here are my codes. Please help. Thanks

```
Dim Data2 = ws.GetServiceByPersonID(hidPersonID.Value)
If Not Data2 Is Nothing Then
       For i = 0 To chkServiceName.Items.Count - 1
                            For Each rec In Data2
                                chkServiceName.SelectedValue = rec.ServiceID
                            Next
       Next
 End If
```

Comment: what are your intentions? Are you trying to select anything at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
For Each rec In Data2
    chkServiceName.SelectedValue = rec.ServiceID
Next
```

This always assigns all values from Data2 to your selectedvalue. Ending with the last one. So all "selected"values have the same value.

I would suggest using your outer loop to find the correct value, like this:

```
chkServiceName.SelectedValue = Data2[i].ServiceID
```

(check VB syntax if needed for the indexing)

You certainly don;t want to loop trough all your Data2 records every time, assigining their values every time for no reason :)